# How to use jsp value in the html

Tags: html, jsp

Here is my code:

```
<%
List<MemberShip> memberships =(List<MemberShip>)request.getAttribute("memberships");
if(memberships != null){
    for(MemberShip m : memberships){
        out.println("name  "+m.getMName()+"<br>");
        out.println("phone  "+m.getMPhone()+"<br>");
        out.println("address "+m.getMAddress()+"<br>");
        out.println("e-mail "+m.getMMail()+"<br>");
    }

}
%>
```

---

My question is I want to create a html button  after printing a MemberShip-list m that include a value (m.getNName) to send to a servlet. Is it possible?

just like this way:

Alan  +86123456 address alan@gmail.com   (button :include value:Alan )
Bob  +86123456 address bob@gmail.com   (button :include value:Bob )
...............

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is possible, find the below code:

JSP Code:

```
<form action='/someservlet' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='selectedname' id='selectedname'>
<%
List<MemberShip> memberships =(List<MemberShip>)request.getAttribute("memberships");
if(memberships != null){
   %>
    <table>
    <%
    for(MemberShip m : memberships){
        %>
        <tr>
           <td><%=m.getMName()%></td>
           <td><%=m.getMPhone()%></td>
           <td><%=m.getMAddress()%></td>
           <td><%=m.getMMail()%></td>
           <td><input type="button" value="button" onclick="sendValue('<%=m.getMName()%>')"></td>
        </tr>
        <%
    }
   %>
    </table>
    <%
}
%>
</form>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
<script>
    function sendValue(name) {
       alert(name);
       // here we are setting value to hidden field, so it can be send to your servlet
       document.getElementById('selectedname').value = name;
       // here we are submitting the form
       document.forms[0].submit();
    }
<script>
```

In Servlet:

We can get the value by using the following:

```
String selectedname = request.getParameter('selectedname');
System.out.println('selectedname : '+selectedname);
```

Give it a try :)